# if condition variable met but go to else:

Tags: python-3.x, csv

```
import csv
def Q1():
    variableA = '800'
    variableB = 'North'
    temp_store = {}
    with open(r'C:\TestData\Testing.csv', 'r,') as file:
        reader = csv_reader(file)
        for row in reader:
            if row[1] == variableB and row[2] == variableA:
                temp_store[row[2]] = row[3:]
            else:
                 print("B")
```

Hi everyone,  I had a problem to store the data i want into temp_store variable.. I print out the row[1] and row[2] to make sure that it is the same as variableA and variableB, but it still print("B") even if the variable are matching..

Comment: Are you checking columns 1 and 2? Column 1 and 2 values are in `row[0]` and `row[1]`, respectively. Not in `row[1]` and `row[2]`.

Comment: Hi, yeah, i double check the row[value] and i did not make any mistake on it. thanks for the point our though :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow i got the solution by going around the if condition.

i revise the code into

```
if row[1]==variableB:
    if row[2] == variableA:
```

then the issue i facing will be solved.

But still I'm not sure why the coding below using **and** is not working thought.

```
if row[1] == variableB and row[2] == variableA:
```

If anyone had an idea, please do let me know..

Comment: The two fragments, as written, are functionally identical. Your problem is elsewhere. It would help if you add a data fragment to your question.